# Can i declare a function that could be called from within any object?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a function, say :

```
function logType()
{
    console.log(typeof (this))
}
```

that I would like to cast on any variable of any type

```
var a = function() { return 1; }
var b = 4;
var c = "hello"

a.logType() // logs in console : "function"
b.logType() // logs in console : "number"
c.logType() // logs in console : "string"
```

(of course it's an example)

Is it possible in any way ?

Comment: `logType.call(a)` for example ... you *could* add logType to the `Object.prototype` - but that is not recommended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), and change the function a little bit otherwise it will return "object" for most checks:

```
function logType() {
    var type = ({}).toString.call(this).match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase();
    console.log(type);
}

var a = function() { return 1; }
var b = 4;
var c = "hello"

logType.call(a) // function
logType.call(b) // number
logType.call(c) // string
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4oea452r/1/)

EDIT

If you want to change the prototype you can do something like this:

```
if (!('logType' in Object.prototype)) {
    Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'logType', {
        value: function () {
            var type = ({}).toString.call(this).match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase();
            console.log(type);
        }
    });
}

a.logType() // function
b.logType() // number
c.logType() // string
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9u4vuyd9/)

Comment: So it's impossible to have it work with the syntax `varname.myfunction()` ?

Comment: You can but, as Jaromanda X said, changing the object prototype isn't recommended.

Comment: @KiJéy, I've added some code that shows you how to change `Object.prototype` to get the result you want.

Comment: Great thank you very much. One last thing, why is it not recommended ? Is it bad practice ?

Comment: @KiJéy, if done incorrectly it will lead to a lot of problems, but this code shouldn't give you any.